# Worklight project not working after update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on worklight 5.0.5 and i upgraded my worklight to 5.0.6 and now it is asking for wlInitOptions not found. I tried to manually create a file with init options but still it is not reading the variable from that file. is there any location that has changed after the upgrade which i need to update in my older project? Help needed

Comment: See my answer below. However, may I ask how come you do not have this file? It exists in 5.0.5 as well. You are the third user to ask this question. Could it be that your application is from before 5.0.5?

Comment: i dont knw why, but i dont have initOptions.js in my project.. the project was not created by me, it was created by someone else of my team and now i am working on it. I dont knw why it is not reading the variable from the file i created manually also.. is there something else i am missing to add as a reference?

Comment: @Idan,I have seen one of ur answers about similar question. you mentioned that WL.Client.init() should not be referenced in the main html? should we remove <script src="js/initOptions.js"/> from the main html too?

Comment: No. You must obviously keep this, as WL.Client.init is being used in initOptions.js

Comment: i added <script src="js/initOptions.js"/> in main file, and  body onload="WL.Client.init({})" and created js file. still i am getting wlInitOptions not found.. is there anything i am missing to add reference?

Comment: 1) Create a NEW application and look at its HTML; adjust yours accordingly. 2) Copy from this application the initOptions.js file (located under common\js) and place it at the same location in YOUR project.

Comment: i tried that too.. i am getting an error, 
 "Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://jazz.net refused"

Comment: Then this is a different issue altogether now and is not related to this question.

Comment: @idan, I understand.. thats why i posted a new question.. anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: If the answer below resolved this specific question for you, please mark it as Answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new application, copy from its common\js folder the initOptions.js file. Next, place this file in your own application's common\js folder.